# Yellowed bookmark

Tags: support, user-interface, bookmarks

I recently noticed that one of my bookmarks is yellow. I have no idea why this is the case. Does someone have an explanation?

[image]

Comment: [What does highlighting mean on the profile's "Favorites" tab?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114274/289905)

Comment: I don't like this design... but I wouldn't know how to do it better in the current layout of the site.

Comment: Don't eat the yellow bookmark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the source code of the page, you would find out that the bookmark is yellow because it has the CSS class `bg-yellow-050`. Which means it is yellow because it is yellow...

More usefully, perhaps it is yellow because it was recently updated. I wondered about this recently as well and the only correlation I could make is that after clicking the bookmark it said it was active recently. And "active" means that either a new answer was posted or there was an update to question/answer(s).

I am not sure when the system decides to colour in a bookmark as being active. I suspect it is "since the last time you opened the bookmarks page".

Comment: If it operates the same way as the highlighting for "Responses" does, then yes, it's since the last time you looked at it.

Comment: Yeah, Responses is something I almost ever use. I just opened it now (to see what you mean) and it might be the fourth or fourth time I've opened it. At least once I misclicked, at least once (other than now) I've opened it deliberately to see what it is in the first place. There might have been 1-2 other times I've opened it, I suppose.